# How do we determine whether the airfoil trailing edge should be cusped or pointed?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I'm working on a project and I need to decide whether an airfoil has a cusped or pointed trailing edge given the x and y coordinates of the airfoil.

What is the difference between the two trailing edges?

Answer (score 3):

Both cusped and conventional airfoils have pointed trailing edges. The lower trailing surface is concave on cusped airfoils, so plot it and get your straightedge. [image: Cusp]

Answer (score 1):

In geometry a cusp is formed when two lines converge to the same tangent, or, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) puts it:

> a point on a curve where a moving point on the curve must start to move backward

For airfoils with an infinitesimally thin trailing edge, the two options are either a point or a cusp:

[image]

In real life, an airfoil will have neither, as the trailing edge will have a finite thickness, but for design and analysis purposes, a point or cusp are simpler to work with.

The issues with cusps were well known to early aerodynamicists, as the [Zhukovsky transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform) produces cusped airfoils, which are impossible to construct in reality, as the converging tangents at the trailing edge also demand infinitesimal thickness.